# Even if I give the right Input it still showing the error alert message

Tags: javascript, html, design-patterns

This is the code

```js
let first = document.getElementById('name');



function check() {
  var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  var res = pattern.test(first.value);

  if (first.value != res) {
    alert('Invalid First Name');
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name"></div>
<button type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary signupbtn" onclick="check()">
Sign Up
</button>
```

I have tried keeping (first.value = res) and then executing. This time it is giving alert message only when there is correct input but not when wrong input. But as keep (first.value != res) then it is showing error message every time I press the signup button.

Comment: The test method [returns a boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) `true` or `false` so of course you get the alert every time (so long as the input value isn't precisely "true" or "false"). If you're just testing if the value matches the regex then just `if (res)` will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **.test()** method returns a boolean. You just need to check if the value matches the regex if not you can run the alert.

```
 let first = document.getElementById('name');
    
    
    function check() {
      var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
      var res = pattern.test(first.value);
      console.log(first.value)
      
      if(!res){
        alert('Invalid First Name');
      } 
      
    }
```